# What is the swallow widget in Edje used for?

Tags: linux, user-interface

I am using EFL (the Enlightenment Foundation Library) for Linux GUI development. I don't get the meaning of the swallow widget that is used in Edje. What is its use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's used to replace the edje part by a widget in C (the edje part is swallowed by the C Widget).

For example, you can create a swallow part and replace it with an elementary entry:

edje:

```
part {
    name: "my_swallow_part";
    type: SWALLOW;
    description {
        //You put desired position here
    } 
}
```

in C:

```
Evas_Object* entry = elm_entry_add(parent_win);
elm_object_content_part_set(layout, "my_swallow_part", entry);
```

And voilà, you have an C widget that you have positioned throught edje.

Note that you could use EXTERNAL in this case (with source: "elm/entry")